# Regex replace second pattern by mapping [0-9] to [q-p] in Geany?

Tags: regular-expression, geany

I would like to replace `123 456 789` with `q23 r56 u89` using [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) regex. So far I can do it with multiple find and replace patterns like this:

```
...      
Find:    `(\D|^)4`    
Replace: `\1r`    


Find:    `(\D|^)5`    
Replace: `\1t`    
...
```

I want to combine these 10 statements into one using mapping of `\2` by the rule `[1234567890] -> [qwertyuiop]`.

How can I do this in geany?

Comment: Filter it through `sed` using `y`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That would not work on his example.

Comment: I hate to be the 'use another tool' guy, but why not use `tr`? I can give answer using that if you so desire,

Comment: @Cyclic3 how to do it in tr? I will accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that can be done with a single regex, as there's no way to look inside a captured group. But Perl can do that in one line, since it allows running a transliteration within a substitution:

```
$ echo 123 456 789 | perl -pe 's/\b[0-9]/ $& =~ tr,1-90,qwertyuiop,r /ge'
q23 r56 u89
```

<sub>(The `s/pattern/replacement/` is a `sed`-style find+replace operator, `\b` matches a word border. The `e` after the final `/` makes the replacement an expression, and the snippet there uses `tr///` to transliterate `$&`, the variable containing the matched text. Arbitrary characters can be used as delimiters for `tr`, so the comma is used to not clash with the outer operator.)</sub>

Of course this doesn't really help that much if you want to do it within Geany.

Comment: @Stepan Yeah this looks impossible with both sed and tr. I would accept this answer, as it appears to be actaully impossible to achieve this with `tr` or `sed`, without sentient regex.